# JSON decode only one data php

Tags: php, json

I have JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "title": "red",
  },
  {
    "title": "blue",
  },
  {
    "title": "yellow",
  },

]
```

I want to get **only** first data, **red**.
I try with this

```
    ...

    $json_output=curl_exec($ch);
    $mydata = json_decode($json_output);

  $result = $mydata->title;

    echo $result[1];
```

and

```
$result = $mydata->title[1];
```

but dont work.

How i can get only first "title" data from this json?

Comment: `var_dump($mydata)` What do you see?

Comment: `json_decode($json_output, true)` -> `$mydata[1]['title'] // blue`

Comment: @Xorifelse It's index `0`. OP wrongly uses index `1` to get the first entry which is obviously wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry, all out of flags ;)

Comment: With all those trailing commas, that isn't valid JSON to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
$json_output=curl_exec($ch);
$mydata = json_decode($json_output);

$result = $mydata[0]->title;
echo $result;
```

Comment: Any explanations to this post?

Comment: $mydata is an array of objects. so you need to access its index $mydata[0].

Comment: Also add the fact the the current JSON string is not valid format. `null` is returned when it fails

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JSON is not valid. You can use [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) validator to check if your JSON is valid. It should look like the following:

```
[
  {
    "title": "red"
  },
  {
    "title": "blue"
  },
  {
    "title": "yellow"
  }

]
```

There are two ways of accessing the JSON object:

1. Array of objects:

   ```
   $mydata = json_decode($json_output);
   $title = $mydata[0]->title; // red
   ```
2. Associative array:

   ```
   $mydata = json_decode($json_output, true);
   $title = $mydata[0]['title']; // red
   ```

See [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information.

Comment: i based my answer from this output you shown [
  {
    "title": "red",
  },
  {
    "title": "blue",
  },
  {
    "title": "yellow",
  },

]

Comment: @GianTomakin I don't think this comment belongs to this answer xD

Comment: You don't have to convert it to an array. `$title = $mydata[0]->title;` works just as well.

Comment: Also add the fact the the current JSON string is not valid format. `null` is returned when it fails.

Comment: @Xorifelse I added it. I also used a JSON validator and you were right

Comment: @rbr94 It was Don't Panic who mentioned it first.

Answer (score 1):

According to PHP's manual, [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns the value encoded in JSON in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the JSON cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

```
<?php
    $json_output = '[{ "title": "red" }, { "title": "blue" }, { "title": "yellow" }]';
    $mydata = json_decode($json_output);
    var_dump($mydata);
    /* Output:
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(3) "red"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(4) "blue"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(6) "yellow"
      }
    }
    */
    echo $mydata[0]->title;
    // Output: red
?>
```

When 2nd parameter is TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
<?php
    $json_output = '[{ "title": "red" }, { "title": "blue" }, { "title": "yellow" }]';
    $mydata = json_decode($json_output, TRUE);
    var_dump($mydata);
    /* Ouput:
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(3) "red"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(4) "blue"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(1) {
        ["title"]=>
        string(6) "yellow"
      }
    }
    */
    echo $mydata[0]['title'];
    // Output: red
?>
```

On a side note, accessing elements within an object that contain any character not allowed under PHP's naming convention can be done by wrapping the index with a curly bracket.

```
<?php
    $json_output = '[{ "h1-title": "red" }, { "h1-title": "blue" }, { "h1-title": "yellow" }]';
    $mydata = json_decode($json_output);
    var_dump($mydata);
    /* Output:
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
        ["h1-title"]=>
        string(3) "red"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
        ["h1-title"]=>
        string(4) "blue"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
        ["h1-title"]=>
        string(6) "yellow"
      }
    }
    */
    echo $mydata[0]->{'h1-title'};
    // Output: red
?>
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't put to much time in an *about to close* answer, especially when its a lower ranked user. They seem to forget they asked this question, don't even mark or+1 it, but hey all `+1` from me for effort.